# Radiobutton presets not carrying over in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to make a settings page that reads the settings from a text file and sets the radio-button variables to these. The function works perfectly when I run it individually. However, when I run it inside of another tkinter program, the preset settings do not show up. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
from Tkinter import *

def format():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x480+400+240")
    root.configure(background='#9E9E9E')

    time_format = IntVar()
    time_format.set(12)

    Time_Format1 = Radiobutton(root, text="12 Hour Format(AM/PM)", font="georgia 12 bold", bg="#1E88E5", activebackground="#64B5F6", fg="black", activeforeground="black", highlightbackground="#212121", variable=time_format, value=12, indicatoron=0)

    Time_Format2 = Radiobutton(root, text="24 Hour Format", font="georgia 12 bold", bg="#1E88E5", activebackground="#64B5F6", fg="black", activeforeground="black", highlightbackground="#212121", variable=time_format, value=24, indicatoron=0)

    Time_Format1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    Time_Format2.grid(row=1,column=0)

    root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x480+400+240")
root.configure(background='#9E9E9E')


Open_time = Button(root, text="Open Date & Time settings", command=format)
Open_time.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cant have two `root.mainloop()`. In Tk, need only to use one.

Comment: keep only one `mainloop()` and use `Toplevel()` to create second window.

Comment: I finally figured it out. All I had to do was create a label that read the variable. I didn't display the label but i think it prevents the variable from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter can have only one main window - `Tk()`
But it may have many dialog windows or other (sub)windows created with `Toplevel()`.

Tkinter can have only one `mainloop()`.

```
from Tkinter import *

def format():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry("800x480+400+240")
    root.configure(background='#9E9E9E')

    time_format = IntVar()
    time_format.set(12)

    time_format1 = Radiobutton(root, text="12 Hour Format(AM/PM)", font="georgia 12 bold", bg="#1E88E5", activebackground="#64B5F6", fg="black", activeforeground="black", highlightbackground="#212121", variable=time_format, value=12, indicatoron=0)
    time_format2 = Radiobutton(root, text="24 Hour Format", font="georgia 12 bold", bg="#1E88E5", activebackground="#64B5F6", fg="black", activeforeground="black", highlightbackground="#212121", variable=time_format, value=24, indicatoron=0)

    time_format1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    time_format2.grid(row=1,column=0)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x480+400+240")
root.configure(background='#9E9E9E')

open_time = Button(root, text="Open Date & Time settings", command=format)
open_time.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my presets still don't show up. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: do you mean your other code ?  Then you can have thousands other problems and we can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. This code itself does not load my presets. The radio button does not show that it is set to 12.